# Invocation order by a specific attribute

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, attributes, invoke

I have subscribed some methods to an event and wish to invoke them by the specific order I give them like so:

```
foreach (var method in LOAD_DEPENDENCIES.GetInvocationList()
        .OrderBy(x => x.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InvocationOrderAttribute),false)))
{
    method.DynamicInvoke(localStats, this);
}
```

where (of course) the event is `LOAD_DEPENDENCIES` and the attribute is `InvocationOrderAttibute`. **Note** that `foreach`'s body works, the parameters of `DynamicInvoke` are not the issue.

That attribute looks like so:

```
public class InvocationOrderAttribute : Attribute , IComparable
{
    public int order;
    public InvocationOrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return this.order.CompareTo((obj as InvocationOrderAttribute).order);
    }
}
```

I implemented the `IComparable` hoping that `OrderBy` will use that to determine the order.

This doesn't work, by debugging I checked that I never even enter the body of that `foreach` loop. **ALL** the subscribed methods have that attribute.

Question is, what am I doing wrong in the `foreach` loop's LINQ query or in the attribute?

**EDIT:**

it ain't the best but works:

```
foreach (var method in LOAD_DEPENDENCIES.GetInvocationList()
       .OrderBy(y => y.Method.GetCustomAttributes(false)
       .OfType<InvocationOrderAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().order))
{
    method.DynamicInvoke(localStats, this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.GetCustomAttributes` returns an `object[]`, so `.OrderBy` will use `Comparer<object[]>.Default`, that will throw exceptions at you as it wants to use some `IComparable` implementation on the type `object[]`, which does not exist.

Instead you should use `.GetCustomAttribute<InvocationOrderAttribute>`, which returns the attribute or null if no such attribute is present. How do methods without the attribute compare to those having one?

Just wrote a small example that works with no event handlers as well as with event handlers not carrying the attribute, where the latter precede the former in the ordering. The event is of delegate type `Action` in the example (yours is something else).

**EDIT**: C# 4.0 capable version without `CustomAttributeExtensions`

The attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class InvocationOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; private set; }

    public InvocationOrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        Order = order;
    }
}
```

New: useful method for all types of events

```
/// <summary>
/// Get individual handlers of the invocation list of the specified <paramref name="@event"/>,
/// ordered by the <see cref="InvocationOrderAttribute"/> of the handler's method.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TDelegate">Delegate type of the <paramref name="@event"/>.</typeparam>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException"><typeparamref name="TDelegate"/> is not a delegate type.</exception>
/// <remarks>Handlers without the attribute come last.</remarks>
public static IEnumerable<TDelegate> OrderedInvocationList<TDelegate>(TDelegate @event)
{
    if (!typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TDelegate)))
        throw new ArgumentException(typeof(TDelegate) + " is not a delegate type.");

    if (@event == null) // empty invocation list
        return Enumerable.Empty<TDelegate>();

    return ((Delegate)(object)@event).GetInvocationList()
        .Select(handler =>
        {
            var attribute = (InvocationOrderAttribute)handler.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InvocationOrderAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
            return new
            {
                Handler = (TDelegate)(object)handler,
                Order = attribute != null ? attribute.Order : int.MaxValue
            };
        })
        .OrderBy(ho => ho.Order)
        .Select(ho => ho.Handler);
}
```

Usage:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static event Action Event;

    private static void RaiseEvent()
    {
        foreach (var h in MyAwesomeCode.OrderedInvocationList(Event))
            h();
    }

    [InvocationOrder(1)]
    private static void M1() { Console.WriteLine("M1"); }

    [InvocationOrder(2)]
    private static void M2() { Console.WriteLine("M2"); }

    private static void M3() { Console.WriteLine("M3"); }

    public static void Main()
    {
        RaiseEvent(); // works on empty invocation list

        Event += M3;
        Event += M2;
        Event += M1;
        Event += M3;
        Event += M2;
        Event += M1;

        RaiseEvent(); // works with methods not carrying the attribute
    }
}
```

Output: M1 M1 M2 M2 M3 M3

The improvements over your code (including 2nd solution):

- No `NullReferenceException` if no handlers registered.
- No `NullReferenceException` if some handler has no attribute.
- Not reflecting the attribute during the sort.
- Applicable for all event delegate types.
- No `.DynamicIvoke` (ugly, not refactoring friendly, inefficient)
- (Not calling a delegate "method", using standard casing of identifiers.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I'm using this for Unity and with the version c# 4, where I don't have a `GetCustomAttribute<>` (maybe not because of the version but I don't have one). What workaround would work in this case?

Comment: `.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<InvocationOrderAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()` is equivalent

Comment: No luck :/ still doesn't do what i wish.

Comment: In what way? Not entering the loop or not ordering correctly? You write the loop never even gets entered... how did you know the `.DynamicInvoke` worked then?

Comment: I looked for one method by name (input as string) :D 
Now I think i got it to work, editing the question with the answer. 
I do accept yours as it should work if not for the limited Unity c#.

Comment: Your solution has still some flaws. Edited my solution to be reliable and more easily and generally usable.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks!